# mySQL display trigger after INSERT - not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a simple trigger which displays the highest id number from a table after it's updated.

I've worked out how to display the last id number but I'm having trouble defining the trigger. My table that I will be updating is rental. I want to display the rental_id, rental_date and the due_date - all coming from the rental table, when I update the rental table.

Any suggestions where I'm going wrong? The below code gives me an error message of not allowed to return a result set from a trigger.
Thanks

```
DELIMITER \\
create trigger receipt
after update on rental 
for each row
begin
select rental_id, rental_date, due_date from rental
order by rental_id desc
limit 1;
end;
\\
```

Comment: The error message says it all: you are not allowed to return a result set from a trigger. Where would you think the result would be displayed anyway? If you want to display something, query it where you want to display it (e.g. your app).

Comment: Right but that's what I don't understand, what's stopping it displaying the last update? Triggers are able to display things like new & old column values, so why can't you call the last update? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: To get over it I've created a view and will call it after an update but this seems inefficient

Comment: No. A trigger can USE old and new values, not display them. It makes no sense for a trigger to display something. Image google (-> your database) changes their data (-> your table) for some reason. You will not know about this unless you ask google (-> call your view/query your table) about it with and display it in your browser (-> the client/app that displays your data/uses your database). If google (or an advertiser) wanted to display the change on your pc without you requesting that (e.g. closed your browser), it should get a similar error ("you cannot display stuff on Bake.G's pc").

Comment: Ok fair enough, that's a shame then, Thanks for the explanation